# How do I create unequal column widths using columnsets?

Tags: context, context-mkiv

I would like to create a columnset where the first column is wider than the others. I understand that column breaks become complicated in such an environment.

The ConTeXt [columns manual](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/columns.pdf) claims to explain how to make one column in a columnset wider than the others, with limitations. It gives code like:

```
\usemodule[visual]

\definecolumnset[example][n=4]

\setupcolumnset[example][1][width=.3\makeupwidth]
\starttext
\startcolumnset[example]
\dorecurse{25}{\fakewords{50}{75}\column[local]}
\stopcolumnset
\stoptext
```

Unfortunately, compiling this results in four columns of *equal* width. How do I make this work as demonstrated in the manual? I'm using mkiv.

Comment: I would suggest that you post this on the Context mailing list. The columnset code has not been ported to MkIV, and it would be done only if there is user demand (and user testing).

Comment: @Aditya Apparently `columnset` has been [ported to MkIV](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/HEAD:/tex/context/base/page-set.mkiv) (judging from the file extension) but the example still fails.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the `newcolumnsets` module which ports parts of the old MKII columnsets to MKIV.  However, the syntax has changed quite a bit, so beware.  There is a [manual](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/columnsets.pdf) but it's a bit incomplete.  If you can't find something there, just ask on the mailing list.

```
\showframe
\usemodule[newcolumnsets,visual]

\definecolumnset[example][n=4,distance=0.0333\makeupwidth]

% left page (even page numbers)
\setupcolumnset[example:1][width=.3\makeupwidth]
\setupcolumnset[example:2][width=.2\makeupwidth]
\setupcolumnset[example:3][width=.2\makeupwidth]
\setupcolumnset[example:4][width=.2\makeupwidth]
% right page (odd page numbers)
\setupcolumnset[example:5][width=.3\makeupwidth]
\setupcolumnset[example:6][width=.2\makeupwidth]
\setupcolumnset[example:7][width=.2\makeupwidth]
\setupcolumnset[example:8][width=.2\makeupwidth]

\starttext

\startcolumnset[example]
  \dorecurse{25}{\fakewords{50}{75}\column}
\stopcolumnset

\stoptext
```

If you don't want to repeat yourself so much, you can also set `width` in the instance and group columns together in the setup.  This makes sense, if all but one column have the same width.

```
\definecolumnset
  [example]
  [n=4,
   width=.2\makeupwidth,
   distance=0.0333\makeupwidth]

\setupcolumnset
  [example:1,example:5]
  [width=.3\makeupwidth]
```

[image]